# VBA code for Pasting below existing data not working, if it has value in single row

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am writing VBA code to paste data below already existing data, which i have earlier done as well. this time code is pasting data only when it has value in more than 1 row. If it has value in single row it will copy, but wont paste. Code is below, any help is really appreciated:

```vb
range(range("a1:c5"), range("a:c").End(xldown)).select
selection.copy
sheets("finalNo").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xLUp).offset(1,0).Pastespecial xlpastevalues
```

this code will not paste anything if the value is in single row only, but will paste perfectly if its in more than two rows. Unable to solve this. Please help.

Comment: this will select the data from a1 to c5 row, which its doing fine. currently i have given it "5" to run a test chek. otherwise, it should select all the available data.

Comment: Didn't you see the selection? How to paste all columns somewhere else than in the first row? There is no place... Try putting `Debug.print selection.Address:stop` after selection. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try here:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        i = LastRow(.Cells.Parent)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(i, "C")).Copy
        Sheets("finalNo").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

- The "magic" comes from using the function `LastRow()`, which gives the last used row in the worksheet, named "Sheet1".
- The `.Cells.Parent` refers to the worksheet om the With-clause. But instead it could be written like this `i = LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1"))`, which is the same.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Will check n let u know..Many thanks again